# Machine needing to restart after binary update of desktop application

Tags: c#, winforms

We have one **Desktop application** build with **.NET3.5 in VS 2008**.  It is **deployed on Network location** which is accessible across the firm.  Shortcut is created on user's machine to start the application. Desktop is being build (compiled) in **AnyCPU configuration** as Some user using **XP** machine and some are using **Windows 7**.  Whenever new build (dlls and exe) deployed on network location, user have to close the app and restart it to work properly

### **Problem**

We are facing a issue whenever we deploy new build (dlls and EXE) of the application. On **Windows 7 machine application is not starting if we close the current running instance**.  User has to restart the machine itself to get it work.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: AnyCPU has **nothing** to do with Windows 7 vs Windows XP.

Comment: Also: if this is a corporate LAN, with no legacy win32 dependencies, have you considered ClickOnce deployment?

Comment: Yes re-start of application is a must if a program is updated. For windows 7 machine application it's a weird issue  because .Net is a copy and paste deployment unless you have used new dlls.

Comment: We copy paste the DLLs on staging location which is actually a unix location  using classic FTP.  Then VMS commands are fired to deployed to production location. It is simply a copy paste.

Comment: Do you experience the same problem closing the program before updating as closing after?

Comment: It happens only when application already ran once before updating the binaries. It doesn't matter whether we close program before/after the update.

Comment: I echo Joel's comment. Go for ClickOnce deployment

Answer (score 0):

There is limited info to go on but the first thing I would make sure of, is the application still running under the Processes tab in the task Manager?

Go to the task manager on the computer and check the running processes tab to see if this app is still running.

It could be that it doesn't shut itself down properly after the user quits the application.

If the program is still running in the background then Windows will require a restart before the new dll's are loaded.